# check whether a user downloaded a file from private system file?

Tags: 8, users, commerce, files

What I wanted to do is to show a tick icon (just next to download link), after a member downloaded a private file, which implemented by [Protected File Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/protected_file) (files are saved on private file system).

I am using Drupal 8, thanks for any help.

Comment: That's basically not possible, the browser doesn't inform you when the download has finished, so you'll only know that the user clicked a link, not that they got the file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download to get an idea of the job you've got ahead of you if you want to implement one of the possible hacks around it. None of them are reliable though

Comment: @Clive Detecting user clicked a link and show a tick icon will be find, any idea how to implement it? thanks!